# How to add image bottom of the tableview in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I want to add image on bottom of the tableview. But it should not scroll along with tableview

Please anybody have idea please share.

I am trying as follows

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:img];
imgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, img.size.height);
CGRect frame = imgView.frame;
frame.origin.x = 0;
frame.origin.y = self.tableView.frame.size.height - img.size.height;
imgView.frame = frame;
imgView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
[self.view addSubview:imgView];
```

But it is scrolling along with tableview

Comment: if your add it to the tableview it will be inside the scroll view of the table and because of that it will scroll. just make your table view a little smaller and put the image view bellow it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an image ON TOP of the table, not within the table (or as a "footer" view)

You can do it like this in your storyboard or XIB file:

[image: image view is above the table view]

Comment: I am trying to set frame of the tableview in storyboard. But tableview frame options are disable. I am using prototype cells with tableviewstyle plain

Comment: are you using a subclassed UIViewController or a UITableViewController for your view controller?

Comment: I iam using subclass of uitableview controller

Comment: Try doing this as a subclass of UIViewController, then your table view height will be adjustable. Having it as a UITableViewController means the whole screen / view is the table, and you don't gain too much advantage for using UITableViewController.

Comment: Thanks Michael its working perfect after changing UITableViewcontroller to UIViewController, Now i am able to set frame of the tableview

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setTableFooterView` method of `UITableview, to set a view at the bottom of the table view.

Swift:

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIImageView(image: myImageView)
```

Objective-C:

```
[[self tableView] setTableFooterView:[self myImageview]];
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
    - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bluebar.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage] autorelease];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,300,100);
return imageView;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 10;
}
```

U can add your image to the footer.

OR

U can create a cell and add image image to that custom cell and attach that cell to footer

Answer (score 0):

change in your code

```
frame.origin.y = self.tableView.frame.size.height + self.tableView.frame.origin.y;
```